# How can I start Apache Cassandra programmatically

Tags: java, cassandra

Hi I want to embed Apache Cassandra in my Java program, how can I start it programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://prettyprint.me/prettyprint.me/2010/02/14/running-cassandra-as-an-embedded-service/index.html
has written a nice blog post on how to embedd cassandra for unittests

Comment: I know this article. The solution is based on org.apache.cassandra.service.EmbeddedCassandraService which only has only a run method. I wonder how I can cleanly shutdown Cassandra with this solution.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "clean shutdown" to Cassandra, just let it die and it will take care of any log replay necessary the next time you start it.

Comment: Sadly is really hard to let it just die. I think I will have to fork another jvm to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We do this in our test utils module now (which also has no dependency on hector-core)

https://github.com/rantav/hector/tree/master/test/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/hector/testutils

As mentioned in the comments, there is no clean shutdown state. It is safe to just kill.